# Replace inequalities with values in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, inequalities

I have a dataframe that involves several columns, in which there are many instances where inequalities are present. What I would like to have, is an R script that will identify these inequalities and replace them with actual values. More specific, let's assume that we have "<2" and we want to replace it with its half value ("<2" -> 1.0). Is there a generic way to do it so that I do not need to find manually all the inequalities within the dataframe and replace them?

A simple example  might be the following:

Col1,Col2, Col3, Col4
2.2, <3, 4,<2
3.4, 4, <5,3
4.2, 2,2.1,5
1.3, 1,4,<8

And I want to get something like this:

Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
2.2, 1.5, 4,1
3.4, 4, 2,5,3
4.2, 2,2.1,5
1.3, 1,4,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can replace the `<` with an expression and `eval`uate

```
df1[] <-  lapply(df1, function(x) sapply(sub("<", "(1/2)*", x, fixed = TRUE), 
     function(y) eval(parse(text = y))))

df1
#  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
#1  2.2  1.5  4.0    1
#2  3.4  4.0  2.5    3
#3  4.2  2.0  2.1    5
#4  1.3  1.0  4.0    4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c(2.2, 3.4, 4.2, 1.3), Col2 = c("<3", "4", 
"2", "1"), Col3 = c("4", "<5", "2.1", "4"), Col4 = c("<2", "3", 
"5", "<8")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I found something that looks like yours:  dataframe[] <- lapply(dataframe, function(x) 0.55*as.numeric(gsub("[<,]", "", x))). Is there any non-trivial difference between this expression and yours?

Comment: @ΚΩΝΣΤΑΝΤΙΝΟΣΠΑΝΑΓΙΩΤΟΥ your code is kind of multiplying all elements with 0.55 and not limiting to `>`, thus answer would be wrong `lapply(df1, function(x) 0.55*as.numeric(gsub("[<,]", "", x)))`